# How does File Vault 2 handle a Windows 7 virtual machine

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, vmware, filevault

Thinking about using File Vault 2 on 2010 macbook air.  I have a windows 7 virtual machine using vm fusionware that is 13 gb large.  What/how will File Vault 2 handle this large space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Filevault 2 encryption happens on the fly** while the system is running.

It does not affect a specific process or application. However, it does affect the I/O performance to the disk. Because Virtual Machines have a lot of read/write operations to the hard drive, the Machine will start slower when loading from the disk.

I have 15GB Virtual Box image for Ubuntu 11.10. It runs very good because my CPU supports the **New AES Instructions for accelerated encryption** which Filevault 2 makes use of.

*In answer to your question:*

- As long as you still have 10-15% of total free space on your hard disk, Filevault 2 will handle any large VM.
- But, I've looked up the Intel processors used in the 2010 Macbook air models. Unfortunately, [none of them support](http://ark.intel.com/compare/37262,37264,36689,36697) the accelerated encryption!

  - Because your Macbook Air is not very powerful, I do not recommend using VMs in Filevault 2, or Filevault 2 at all, if you don't really need it.
  - Enabling Filvault 2 will cause large drops in reading/writing speeds to your flash drive without accelerated encryption.

Also see:

- [Intel® Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-aes-instructions-set/)
- [Filevault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790)